Is Wordpress based on PHP?
Is Wordpress based on PHP or does it use another language?

Why have you deleted the content of this question and re-named it? You should start a new question instead.

I was new to SO and I asked a question I could have researched myself, a mistake.

Yes, WordPress is one type of CMS and you are right, WordPress is based on PHP

Sorry for the hassle - so many downvoters!
